# ¿Cómo puedo poner diferente color a cada barra?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una duda tengo una barra de tarea pero necesito cambiar el color de cada una de las barras estoy utilizando Morris Bar.
Estoy agregando un arreglo y es dinámico pero solo me sale un color de todas las barras cómo es que se debe llamar los colores.

```
var bar = new Morris.Bar({
  element: 'bar-chart',
  resize: true,
  data: [
  <?php

      echo "{y: '".$arrayestado[0]."',a:'".$estados[0]."'},";
      echo "{y: '".$arrayestado[1]."',a:'".$estados[1]."'},";
      echo "{y: '".$arrayestado[2]."',a:'".$estados[2]."'},";
      echo "{y: '".$arrayestado[3]."',a:'".$estados[3]."'},";
      echo "{y: '".$arrayestado[4]."',a:'".$estados[4]."'},";
      echo "{y: '".$arrayestado[5]."',a:'".$estados[5]."'},";
      echo "{y: '".$arrayestado[6]."',a:'".$estados[6]."'},";
      echo "{y: '".$arrayestado[7]."',a:'".$estados[7]."'},";

  ?>
  ],
  barColors: ['#FF8D33','#469427','#469427','#469427','#469427','#469427','#469427','#469427'],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a'],
  labels: ['jj'],
  preUnits: '',
  hideHover: 'auto'
});
</script>
```

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha servido, que por lo que he visto en otra pregunta, así es. Por favor marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Me pregunto porque necesitas hacer tantos echos cuando podrías utilizar un bucle for: `for ($i = 0; $i <= count($arrayestado); $i++) {echo "{y: '".$arrayestado[$i]."',a:'".$estados[$i]."'},";}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que he visto en los ejemplos del [Github MorrisBar](https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js):

Parece que solo lee un color cada vez que genera una barra. Por lo que puedes asignar un color a cada barra retornando el color mediante una función que lea la barra en la que está actualmente:

```
barColors: function (row, series, type) {
        switch(row.y){
        case 1: {
            return '#FF8D33';
        }case 2: {
            return '#469427';
        }case 3: {
            return 'blue';
        }case 4: {
            return 'red';
        }default:{
            return '#FFF';
        } 
    }
},
```

**Nota:**

> `row.y` es igual al "label" de cada columna.

Por lo que si nuestra columna 1 se llama "edad"
en el case del switch tendremos que poner

```
case "edad": {
```

Creo que era necesario clarificarlo tras lo visto en la siguiente pregunta [Cambiar el color de cada barra de un gráfico con Morris Chart](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/275747/cambiar-el-color-de-cada-barra-de-un-gr%C3%A1fico-con-morris-chart)

[Ejemplo bar-colors](https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/blob/master/examples/bar-colors.html)