# Cambiar el color de cada barra de un gráfico con Morris Chart

Tags: javascript, color

Estoy utilizando Morris bar para graficar pero mis datos son dinámicos mi problema que necesito cambiar cada color de cada barra pero no me sale este es mi codigo gracias.
Ocupo un arreglo para llamar los datos y son 8 y los 8 corresponde a cada cada bara de tareas. No se si este bien la función barColor para llamar o a que se debe que no cambie el color por cada barra.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
var bar = new Morris.Bar({
  element: 'bar-chart',
  resize: true,
  data: [
  <?php
      echo "{y:'".$arrayestado[0]."',a:'".$estados[0]."'},";
      echo "{y:'".$arrayestado[1]."',a:'".$estados[1]."'},";
      echo "{y:'".$arrayestado[2]."',a:'".$estados[2]."'},";
      echo "{y:'".$arrayestado[3]."',a:'".$estados[3]."'},";
      echo "{y:'".$arrayestado[4]."',a:'".$estados[4]."'},";
      echo "{y:'".$arrayestado[5]."',a:'".$estados[5]."'},";
      echo "{y:'".$arrayestado[6]."',a:'".$estados[6]."'},";
      echo "{y:'".$arrayestado[7]."',a:'".$estados[7]."'},";          
  ?>
  ],
  barColors: function (row, series, type) {
        switch(row.y){
        case 1: {
            return 'red';
        }case 2: {
            return 'green';
        }case 3: {
            return 'blue';
        }case 4: {
            return 'cyan';
        }case 5:{
          return 'magenta';
        }case 6:{
          return 'purple';
        }case 7:{
          return 'gold';
        }
        default:{
            return 'orange';
        } 
    }
  },
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a'],
  labels: [''],
  preUnits: '',
  hideHover: 'auto'
});
</script>
```

Comment: Viendo ejemplos por internet, lo que aprecio es lo siguiente. El switch, debería ser `row.label`. Y declara el `barColor` al final.

Comment: `xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a'],
  labels: [''],
  preUnits: '',
  hideHover: 'auto',
  barColors: function (row, series, type) {
        switch(row.label){
        case 1: {
            return 'red';
        }case 2: {
            return 'green';
        }case 3: {
            return 'blue';
        }case 4: {
            return 'cyan';
        }case 5:{
          return 'magenta';
        }case 6:{
          return 'purple';
        }case 7:{
          return 'gold';
        }
        default:{
            return 'orange';
        } 
    }
  }`
Ahora todos son naranja

Answer (score 2):

El problema se debe a que `row.y` es igual al *"label"* de cada columna, es decir, `row.y` de la primer columna es igual a `Cerrado`.

### Solución:

Dado que no utilizas ningún ID para detectar e identificar cada fila, sino que simplemente quieres usar el "orden", deberías usar `row.x` (*el cual nos indica la columna a colorear*).

#### Demo:

```js
Morris.Bar({
  element: 'bar-example',
  data: [
    {y: '2006', a: 100},
    {y: '2007', a: 75},
    {y: '2008', a: 50},
    {y: '2009', a: 75},
    {y: '2010', a: 50},
    {y: '2011', a: 75},
    {y: '2012', a: 100}
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a'],
  labels: [''],
  barColors: function(row, series, type) {
    if (type != 'bar') {
      return;
    }
    switch (row.x) {
      case 0: return 'red';
      case 1: return 'green';
      case 2: return 'blue';
      case 3: return 'cyan';
      case 4: return 'magenta';
      case 5: return 'purple';
      case 6: return 'gold';
      default: return 'orange';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>

<div id="bar-example"></div>
```